# How to query documents from an entire MongoDB database containing multiple collections at once (Pymongo)

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a DB containing thousands of collections, each collection containing documents.
How would I query all these documents from all the collections at once?

I have considered using the `$lookup` aggregation method but from my knowledge, it only combines an additional collection at once, whereas I have thousands of collections that I want to combine and query altogether.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB operations work on a single collection at a time. As you point out, $lookup can perform a cross-collection lookup, but it won't help you with a large number collections.

Re-design your data model.